# Ensuring transactional writes across two delta tables in databricks

Tags: python, databricks

I want to create/update two delta tables in databricks. However, I want them both to be created at the same time such that the following can never occur:

1. A user queries table 1 and table 2 and gets the original data from table 1 and the updated data from table 2
2. A user queries table 1 and table 2 and gets the updated data from table 1 and the original data from table 2.

The following is some dummy code to create/update both tables but this wouldn't guarantee the above two conditions are satisfied.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Create dummy data
table1_data = [(1, "A", 10.5, True),
               (2, "B", 20.5, False),
               (3, "C", 30.5, True),
               (4, "D", 40.5, False)]
table2_data = [(1, "E", 50.5, True),
               (2, "F", 60.5, False),
               (3, "G", 70.5, True),
               (4, "H", 80.5, False)]

# Create dataframe
table1_df = spark.createDataFrame(table1_data, ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])
table2_df = spark.createDataFrame(table2_data, ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])

# Write dataframe to delta table
table1_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable("table1")
table2_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable("table2")
```

How can I modify this so that the above two conditions are guaranteed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databricks only guarantees transactions on the table level, and cannot create a transaction on multiple tables like other SQL databases. That is because the transaction log on delta tables exists at the table level (in each table folder).

"Applications that modify multiple tables commit transactions to each table in a serial fashion"

Documentation - [https://docs.databricks.com/en/lakehouse/acid.html#:~:text=Databricks%20manages%20transactions%20at%20the,deadlock%20is%20not%20a%20possibility](https://docs.databricks.com/en/lakehouse/acid.html#:%7E:text=Databricks%20manages%20transactions%20at%20the,deadlock%20is%20not%20a%20possibility).